What other methods are there to solve the problem of determining whether this function inequality is correct or not?
Question:
Given that the domain of function $f(x)$ is $R$, $f(x)>f(x-1)+f(x-2)$, and when $x<3$, $f(x)=x$, which of the following conclusions must be correct?
A. $f(10)>100$ B. $f(20)>1000$
C. $f(10)<1000$ D. $f(20)<10000$

My approach is as follows:
Clear["`*"]
a[n_] = a[n] /. 
   First@RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 2}, 
     a[n], n] // Expand
Table["a" <> ToString[k] <> "=" <> ToString[a[k]], {k, 1, 20, 1}]
Table[a[k], {k, 1, 20, 1}] // Simplify


Based on the specific value of each item, compare it with the answer to see which item is right or wrong. Are there any other methods that can better solve this problem?

Perhaps
F = RSolveValue[{f[n] == f[n - 1] + f[n - 2], f[3] == 3, f[2] == 1},f, n]
Reduce[F[x] >= F[x - 1] + F[x - 2]]
cond = Simplify[%, x >= 3]

Resolve[ForAll[x, x >= 3, cond], Reals] (*True*)

F[n] is the lower  limit of the unknown function a[n].
That's why, because a[n]>=F[n],  we only can check the first two conditions
{F[10] > 100, F[20] > 1000} (* False, True*)

